# Invalid or unexpected token when loading into the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to run an extremely simple `socket.io/express` webserver just to test things out. I'm using express to serve the following `index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            const socket = io();
            console.log("We have sent a request to connect"); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Websocket</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML loads fine but for some reason, I'm getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for `socket.io.js 1`.  When I look at it on chrome there are a bunch of weird characters `摯⁥‽湥潣敤਻敹獡⹴敤潣敤㴠搠捥摯㭥洊摯汵⹥硥潰瑲⁳‽敹獡㭴ਊ⨯⨪ ⥽ਊ⨯`
However, when I simply request `localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js` I get the `socket.io` code I would expect.

This is my `index.js`:

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log("Getting a request to /")
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public' , "index.html"));
})


io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("We are connected");
    console.log(socket.handshake.adress);
 });

httpServer.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 5000");
});
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Look in the Chrome debugger at the Network tab and see what exactly is coming back from the request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  In that Network tab, you can see exactly what the browser requests and exactly what the server sends back.  When you load this page in the browser, are you loading if via the URL `http://localhost:5000`?

Comment: FYI, in this `console.log(socket.handshake.adress);` `.address` is misspelled.

Comment: hey, @jfriend00 thanks I misspell that a lot. Also yeah when I look in the network tab socket.io.js is returning a large file filled with more weird characters such as the ones I commented about.  Also yeah I'm accessing it from http://localhost:5000. I can also access the normal socket.io.js file from http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: I don't know.  Nothing we can really do from here since we can't debug it to examine things.  A couple things to try.  Clear your browser cache.  Reinstall socket.io.  Restart your computer.